# How to access data using VBSCRIPT from a stored procedure which contains values in Temp table?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, vbscript, sybase, qtp

for testing purpose I wrote a VBscript which will fetch values from Sybase by executing a stored procedure which contains values in temp table. When I run the script I get the following errors ,

```
"Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record."
```

or

```
"Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal."
```

Somewhere when I was googling I found that , the above error message will be shown when we use temp table in stored procedure, if that is the reason , then how can I access data via VBscript by executing the stored procedure ?? 
 I am using QTP to run VBScript

Comment: Does this happen only when running the script from QTP? If you create an equivalent pure VBScript script does it not happen? (If so please remove the `qtp` tag, it's misleading.)

Comment: I am using QTP to run VBScripts and debug them

Comment: I can not recommend using QTP as a dev env if all you wanna do is debug VB scripts. There are just too many pitfalls to discovere. Stick to VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Sybase as well but it sounds like the recordset you return either has field names different than what you are expecting OR its not even there.

I assume you are inserting into the temp table and then eventually selecting from it to return the values.
If sybase supports it, use a Set NOCOUNT On at the beginning of your stored proc.

You likely are getting multiple recordsets back and the first one isn't the one you want.